# Generating a heatmap from a image

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0

So I've have trained a simple image classifier in TensorFlow 2.0, I based it on [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification#create_a_dataset), it uses the second method from the website because the first one, where it doesn't use Dropout or Data augmentation overfits a bit.

So now I need to generate a heatmap for where it thinks the class is (I don't need it for flowers like the TensorFlow tutorial).

I watched a Computerphile [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJlAxW-2nmI) which suggests that I should use a CNN for this problem.

So if I do train a network like this would it need photos with the class's positions or just images?

Please answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like Grad-CAM *"..a technique for making Convolutional Neural Network (CNN)-based models more transparent by visualizing the regions of input that are "important" for predictions from these models - or visual explanations."*

Here is some links that covers it from the start.

https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/03/09/grad-cam-visualize-class-activation-maps-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/

https://medium.com/@mohamedchetoui/grad-cam-gradient-weighted-class-activation-mapping-ffd72742243a

And the following is the original paper:

http://gradcam.cloudcv.org/

Comment: So is the TensorFlow flower classification model a CNN?

Comment: @sahalmulki from the link you prvided in the question, yes. either with or without dropout

Comment: Thank you so much after lots of searching stack overflow and google and GitHub i finally got my model to work 